# Navigation Controller Not Applying Changes

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, swift5

I have two view controllers, I then go and embed the first one in a navigation controller and then link it to the second one, however when I go to make changes either the tint bar color or title color, nothing ends up changing. Although when I look at the top of both view controllers it has the white bar with the back button. It's as if none of the changes are being applied or there is something else I need to do to connect it. I have tried adding things through code also and nothing has worked.

Comment: you mean the navigation bar is not showing?

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad The nav bar is showing on all the view controllers although when I go to change any of the properties For EXAMPLE: tint color, back button image, tint bar color, none of the changes show up on the view controller

Comment: can you also please share how you are changing the properties? also print to console navigationBar, i.e `print (navigationBar)` to check if its not null.

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad I am confused what you mean by how am I changing the properties, I just click on the nav bar and a bunch of different choices come up for how i can customize the nav bar.

Comment: So you mean you are changing the tint/color etc from the story board?

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, and your applied changes are not showing up when you are running the application; then try the steps here (likely its some cache issue): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later/6247073#6247073

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad yes but I have also tried changing in in view controller.swift i.e NavigationController?.Navbar etc

Comment: If you can see the changes in Storyboard, but can't see them when you are running the application..then there is some cache issue. Go through the steps in that answer linked above. If still does not work..then lets see what other ways we can check.

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad I can't see the changes in my storyboard, or the simulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215550/discussion-between-mohammad-assad-arshad-and-appledeveloper123).